# Matching a sliced string

Tags: ruby, string

I am trying to use the `case` statement:

```
week # => "03 – 09 MAR 2019"
first_day = week.slice(0..2) # => 03
last_day = week.slice(5..7) # => 09
month = week.slice(8..11) # => MAR
year = week.slice(12..17) # => 2019
puts month # >> MAR
case month
when 'JAN' then month_num = '01'
when 'FEB' then month_num = '02'
when 'MAR' then month_num = '03'
when 'APR' then month_num = '04'
when 'MAY' then month_num = '05'
when 'JUN' then month_num = '06'
when 'JUL' then month_num = '07'
when 'AGO' then month_num = '08'
when 'SEP' then month_num = '09'
when 'OCT' then month_num = '10'
when 'NOV' then month_num = '11'
when 'DEC' then month_num = '12'
else month_num = 'ERROR'
end
puts month_num # >> ERROR
```

However, the `case` statement always goes to the `else` branch.

Why is the var `month_num` equal to the string `"ERROR"` instead of `"03"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `puts` to examine what you have, and therefore you are missing to observe whitespaces in your results. You actually have:

```
week.slice(0..2) # => "03 "
week.slice(5..7) # => "09 "
week.slice(8..11) # => "MAR "
week.slice(12..17) # => "2019"
```

To observe what you have, it is better to use `p` rather than `puts`.

You have the wrong range. Actually, there is no reason to use ranges here. It is much easier to use the second argument to specify the length:

```
week.slice(0, 2) # => "03"
week.slice(5, 2) # => "09"
week.slice(8, 3) # => "MAR"
week.slice(12, 4) # => "2019"
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `month` is `"MAR "`

Try

```
month = week.slice(8..10)
```

And makes sense, from 8 to 10 inclusive are three characters. Same for the other parts.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you want to parse a string containing data in a specific format. Instead of relying on absolute indices, you could use a [regular expression](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Regexp.html) to match the date format, e.g:

```
PATTERN = /
  (?<first_day>\d{2}) # 2-digit first day
  \s*                 # optional whitespace
  [–-]                # delimiter(s)
  \s*
  (?<last_day>\d{2})  # 2-digit last day
  \s*
  (?<month>\w{3})     # 3-letter month name
  \s*
  (?<year>\d{4})      # 4-digit year
/ix
```

To extract the data:

```
str = '03 – 09 MAR 2019'
m = str.match(PATTERN)
#=> #<MatchData "03 – 09 MAR 2019" first_day:"03" last_day:"09" month:"MAR" year:"2019">

m[:first_day] #=> "03"
m[:last_day]  #=> "09"
m[:month]     #=> "MAR"
m[:year]      #=> "2019"
```

The results could further be fed into [`Date.strptime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime):

```
require 'date'

from = m.values_at(:first_day, :month, :year).join(' ') #=> "03 MAR 2019"
to   = m.values_at(:first_day, :month, :year).join(' ') #=> "09 MAR 2019"

Date.strptime(from, '%d %b %Y')  #=> #<Date: 2019-03-03 ...>
Date.strptime(to, '%d %b %Y')    #=> #<Date: 2019-03-09 ...>
```

Or [`_strptime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-_strptime) if you're just interested in the raw values:

```
Date._strptime(from, '%d %b %Y')
#=> {:mday=>3, :mon=>3, :year=>2019}
```